# Save object with one-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a `Company` model and I want to update the `Company` record and save a list of phone numbers all at once.  There is a 1-* relationship.

My ViewModel looks like:

```
public class CompanyRegisterViewModel
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public int CompanyTypeId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompanyTypes { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStringResource))]
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaximumLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationStringResource))]
    public string LicensedCompanyName { get; set; }

    public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Save(Company company)` method, if I call:

```
_context.Companies.Add(company);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Will this save a new company record and save the `List<Phone> Phones` or do I need a transaction and call `SaveChanges()` again to save the `Phones`.  I also need to set `CreatedBy` and `DateCreated` for each `Phone` record.  Should I loop through the `Phone` records prior to saving and update each record in a `foreach` loop?  I want this set automatically in the backend, not in the UI.

Comment: Have you set / configured the relationships in your `OnModelCreating` method?

Comment: Yes.  I think it should update when I call `SaveChanges`, but how can I set the `CreatedBy` and `DateCreated` without looping through each phone record?

Comment: I'm writing up an answer. give me a few minutes

Comment: Thank you, I think I just figured it out.  I created a constructor on my domain model for `Phone` and set the values there.  Go ahead and create your answer though and I'll accept it.

Comment: If you put it in the constructor, be aware that the date will be when that instance was created, not when the record was inserted into the database. If a user leaves his desk for lunch and hits save when he comes back, that might be a difference of a few minutes. You'll have to decide if that matters to you.

Comment: Could you modify your answer to include LastUpdatedBy and LastUpdatedDate also or would this only work for creates?

Comment: That should be trivial. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I broke it up into 2 variables: `insertedEntities` and `updatedEnties`  I only want to set the create fields on the original creation, not the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to automatically set properties like `Modified` and `ModifiedBy` everytime you call SaveChanges or SaveChangesAsync, you have to do 2 things.

Create a base interface, from which all your entities inherit from

```
public interface IEntityRoot
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Inherit all your entites from this interface:

```
  public class Company : IEntityRoot { ... }
```

With this, all entities which inherit from this interface will have the properties `Created` & `CreatedBy`. The last step is to create a small method, which is called every time you save your changes and automatically sets the current date and user.

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    /* ... */
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        TrackModifiedDates();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        TrackModifiedDates();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private void TrackModifiedDates()
    {
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                    .Where(x => x.Entity is IEntityRoot && (x.State == EntityState.Added) || (x.State == EntityState.Modified));
        //if anonymous access is possible, do a null check here.
        var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            if(entity.State == EntityState.Added) 
            {
                ((IEntityRoot)entity.Entity).Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
                ((IEntityRoot)entity.Entity).CreatedBy = userName;
            }  

            ((IEntityRoot)entity.Entity).Modified = DateTime.UtcNow;
            ((IEntityRoot)entity.Entity).ModifiedBy = userName;
        }
    }
}
```